# How to draw control.graphics to bitmap

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I draw image to my pictureBox as:

```
pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(myImage, 0, 0);
```

and i draw some rectangles as:

```
pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(point1, new Size(10, 10)));
```

but whe i use pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(myBitmap,rect) to save an image with rectangles, 
It save the pictureBox control only without graphics and rectangles.
How can i save the Graphics content to bitmap?
There is my code:

```
//to get an image to pictureBox
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
   if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
   {
       Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
       pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));  
   }
}

//this is to draw rectangles
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(e.Location, new Size(10, 10)));
}

//tis is to save graphics to image
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(myBitmap,rect)
   myBitmap.Save("C:\\test.bmp");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(256, 256, gfx);
// now you can save bmp to file on disk
```

And to load it back into memory:

```
// here you must load file from disk into bmp
Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
```

While `bmp` is an actual `Bitmap` I'd recommend saving it in a better format than `BMP`.
The bitmap in memory has to be fully rasterized (all pixels in raw format) so that you can manipulate and render them. But on disk you don't need the raster this way and want to save space, so you normally use a format like `PNG`. For this special case I'd not recommend `JPG`, which is impressively good for pictures. What you need is a lossless encoding like that `PNG` I said before.